# Search view/serializer - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, search, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is there a way to implement a search view in my DRF API? For example, I use the following code on my site to allow the user to enter keywords into a search bar and return results.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'search/results.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_qs = super(SearchListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if query:
            user_qs = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query)
                )
        return user_qs
```

Is there a way to do this in DRF to use for my API?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, this is what filtering is for.

Django REST framework documentation already provides similar example. Have a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters for detail implementation.

Comment: I'm able to add "?q=parameter" to the end of my url and have the results displayed. However, in the example you provided, do you know how to get that search bar to display? I have to do add the parameters manually to the url, which is a little bit a nuisance.

Comment: Maybe you want to edit and rephrase your question, not sure what you're looking for